# Setting up whitelists in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, whitelist

I'm running into the following problem when setting up a whitelist for PHP:

I've set the following filter in the phpunit xml:

```
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../..</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>../../cache</directory>
            <directory>../../public_html</directory>
            <directory>../../temp</directory>
            <directory>../../tools</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```

Without that whitelist, everything works fine, but when I put it, the system crashes because it tries to include all the files. That makes it include a file which has a require_once, and thus it crashes the application.

**EDIT** At startup the system defines some constants. Since those constants ain't defined when it includes all the data to create the whitelist, it tries to access a folder which doesn't exist (PHP assumes the constant is a string), thus the require_once fails, and given it's a require, it crashes.

Also, in case it's of any help, the whitelist is being used to use it with **Selenium**. Maybe that's the source of the problem?

Comment: It works as edorian wrote in our code as well. Perhaps your code is the one doing a bare `require`. Edit your question to add the actual error output as "crashes the application" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Probably you can define that constant in the PHPUnit bootstrap or in your base Testcase?

Comment: wouldn't that go against good practices? Anyway I'll try that, to see if it atleast works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well to collect code coverage information the system kinda **has to** require all the files so that is expected behavior. (Technically it doesn't *have* to, but it does)

If you are using `require_once` that should not be a problem as phpunit also uses a `"_once"` to require the files.

We use whitelisting on a codebase full of require_once statements and the only issue I've run into is having a class that was defined in two places.

Comment: The main problem here is that the code is dependant on a framework, thus, when loaded alone, it crashes (I'm not interested in code coverage of the framework).

Comment: @Lumbendil Usually one bootstraps the framework in the `<phpunit bootstrap="yourBootstrap.php">` but it's not included in the whitelist (or `<excluded>` there). Your problem is that your code requires parts of the framework and that doesn't work out?

Comment: atm I'm just building the **Selenium** tests, that's why the bootstrap currently doesn't bootstrap the framework. We don't have plans to start with the Unit Testing atm, should I bootstrap it anyway to make this work?

Comment: So you are doing selenium and collecting the coverage information like described in http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html#selenium.seleniumtestcase (starting with `Copy PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase/phpunit_coverage.php into your webserver's document root directory.`). I'd say if you want the whitelisting to work just bootstrap the framework but when it comes to Selenium I'm not certain about the best way of doing it

Comment: Well, then I'll simply bootstrap the framework, doubt there is any better option.